# Jquery Replace Function, if there is a way

Tags: jquery, replace

one of my clients is making posts trough WordPad so it adds an extra tag each time he posts, and it's crashing IE.

What i want to do is put a jquery function to replace:

```
<!--[if !supportLists]-->
```

with:

```
<!--[if !supportLists] --> (With a space after [)
```

within whole document.

Is there an easy way do make it work? or should i use PHP?

thanks

Comment: Making posts through WordPad... wow

Comment: Seriously though, I'd be tempted to iron them out server side, then there's no way the content could crash IE and prevent you messing with the DOM :-)

Comment: What i meant was he is using "word" to create html pages, and it is adding extra tags which would show wrongly in internet explorer.

Comment: Change the options in word, so these tags won't be added?

Comment: Using Word... that's even worse! Word knows as much about HTML as my Nan. :D

Comment: Clients can be weird :) I would never use that for an HTML page.

Comment: They can indeed, good luck with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Replace function :

```
function replaceAll(str, from, to)
{
    return str.split(from).join(to);
}
```

You can also use prototype on String :

```
String.prototype.replaceAll(from, to)
{
    return this.split(from).join(to);
}
```

Or I didn't understand your question properly...

Answer (score 0):

Eventhough you do add the space, will it work? 
I mean, the page gets loaded and then the space will be added.
So if IE crashes, won't it crash even before the space is added?

So youre friend just has to use "find and replace" (CTRL + F, if im correct) and replace the first tag with the second (correct) one.

Don't know if this is correct, i'm not a PHP specialist but:
`str_replace("<!--[if !supportLists]-->", "< !--[if !supportLists] -->")`
would that work?

Comment: Yes, one space makes the error go away. i can manually edit this, but i want it to change dynamically so he won't have problems later on.

Comment: See my edit, would that work? If you put that inside you're PHP stuff?